# Petición POST. Vuejs y Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy realizando un sistema de logeo con Vuejs y Laravel 5.4 pero tengo el siguiente error. Anteriormente para probar los CORS lo hice mediante el `GET` y pues sí me dio resultado, sí me mostró el response pero ahora con las peticiones `POST` no sirve .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el método para la conexión:

```js
<script>
export default{ 

 data(){ //Este metodo sirve para la comunicacion de la api de laravel
  return{
   Email:'',
   Password:''

  }
 },

 methods:{
  Login (){

   var data= {
    client_id: 2,
    client_secret: 'z1cYAzOmgJqUys6iWqaylR4jIv1jDXkncRn5IK1g',
    grant_type:'password',
    username: this.Email,
    password: this.Password
   }

   this.$http.post("http://localhost:8000/oauth/token",data) //Hacemos la comunicacion entre Vue y laravel
   .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
   })
  }
 }
}
 
</script>

<style>
 
</style>
```

Comment: Habria que saber como es tu backend. Get no tiene problemas de CORS porque los navegadores lo ignoran. El metodo post manda un options antes (para hacer un pre-flight y comprobar que tiene acceso) y por lo que estas mostrando eso falla. El problema seria tu backend. Trata de acceder al mismo con una aplicacion tipo postman, y si accedes, entonces tenes un problema de CORS

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente cuando el método OPTIONS te truena, es por que tu server lo está rechazando, no le gustó el objeto data en tu post, o bien, tu token de petición está mal o algo por ahí va, no es que tu request este fallando, es que al momento de querer decirle al server " te voy a mandar una cosa" te rechaza y por eso te termina tronando el options, y por ende la promesa del req

Comment: cuando options es rechazado, es por problemas de cors. Tu respuesta es incorrecta